# "uninstal" option missing from "Programs and Features" window? - windows vista

Tags: windows-vista

I'm using windows vista, trying to clean out the laptop (not really mine) and so I'm trying to uninstall all the crap. But when i go to the programs and features window, the uninstall option is missing. If i right click on anything in the list nothing happens. left clicking, double clicking, nothing happens. Can't figure out what to do here.. any help?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Have you recently attempt to free up space using a tool to do so.  If you did then its likely you removed the uninstaller that Windows requires to perform this function.  Verify the uninstaller exists in the uTorrent directory, if its no there, then installing uTorrent will solve the problem.  If it is there is another explanation.

Comment: it's actually not utorrent that i'm trying to get rid of... its a variety of programs and none of them have the "uninstall" option. i have not recently used any tools like such.

Comment: The solution is the same.  Install the application again and it will restore your ability to remove the application.  If it doesn't then were dealing with a User permission problem, and without more information about your specific and exact setup, I can't suggest anything remediation.

Comment: im trying to clean junk.... im not going to instal it again...... i want to get rid of it.

Comment: Please clarify your question the because the programs listed are harmless

Comment: @ramhound the programs shown are not ones i want to get rid of. its just a screenshot to show the uninstall button is missing.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the screenshot, most programs that are listed are not installed, but only their entries remain. This usually happens by removing the programs from the harddrive without properly uninstalling them, or by using an uninstall tool that doesn't work right.

There's a program to clean up this list.

Comment: that makes sense... although there are several junk programs that are definitely installed. and i havent used any uninstal tools or deleted folders.. i just started cleaning this today. is there a virus or something that makes it more difficult to uninstal things by removing the option?

Comment: My knowledge on all the virusses out there is not sufficient to ansewr this, but given that a virus often wants to destroy a pc and make it really hard to be removed, there possibly is a virus out there that could do this. But that would be speculation.

Answer (score 1):

### Causes

This could be happening because of several causes. The most probable cause is that you installed the programs and they were either removed manually from program files folder, or they weren't installed properly. There are several other reasons as well, such as viruses, malware, and adware on your computer that edited the registries that disable uninstalltion of programs.

### Experiment

First of all I would like you to confirm that the software directory itself exits. For uTorrent, the default location of the latest version is `C:\Users\Shahrukh\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent`. If the software does exist on the computer you can proceed to opening regedit.exe (Type it in run or search bar). Once open navigate to this path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\uTorrent
```

If that path exists and you see the UninstallString name, with the value of,

```
"C:\Users\Shahrukh\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe" /UNINSTALL
```

you should be able to technically see the uninstall button. If you don't find the string than the program's registry was edited and the uninstall string doesn't exists. This could be caused by malicious content or as a result of program not being installed properly. IT could also be that you're not logged into to the admin account or the account that installed those applications. Most of the icons for the programs are not shown so my best guess would be that they have been uninstalled improperly.

### Solution

You can either find each program's msi, exe and uninstall it using the proper switch but this option will take lots of time and research for each program that you would like to uninstall. For example to uninstall uTorrent, you would either create a batch file or open up a command prompt screen and paste this line:

```
"C:\Users\Shahrukh\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe" /UNINSTALL
```

Basically the first part of the line points to the exe (either the uninstaller or the program itself - depending on the program itself) or the msi file. then uses the switch /uninstall. This is where the research comes in since the every program has a different format syntax and switch.

The easiest and by far the fastest way would be if you install [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html). This is a  great free software that helps removing all traces of any and all programs installed on your computer. It works much better than the built-in windows programs and feature and it keeps tracks of all files that a program installs so you have the piece of mind when removing software.

Comment: Thank you for that awsome explanation :) tonight I will surely check that out and see if it works :)

Comment: Let me know how to goes. P.S. I hate Windows Vista, I would recommend you upgrade :D.